# Eclipse launch configuration misleading

Tags: eclipse

How to I remove non-current Eclipse C++ launch configuration?

[image: multiple launch configurations confusing]

What I expect is, the RUN directly related to myproject.exe, not pointing to otherproject.exe sometimes. this is misleading and bring up error. So why not let the closed project with its launching configuration, i.e. closedproject.exe be invisible. And It should be automatically visible if I am editing that C++ code?

Yes I did check the menu setting (De-/Selected both tried):

```
Windows->Preference->Run/Debug->Launching->Launch Configurations:

Filter configuration in closed projects
Filter configuration inc deleted or missing projects
```

But the closedproject.exe still in the drop down list or sometime even link to current project build.

What did I wrong or what is the correct/clear setting for this? Or maybe pls. help me to understand why multiple project.exe are listed there?

Or it is a Eclipse improve point?

Comment: I made your screenshot visible (your Stack Overflow reputation is too low for you to do it yourself). In _Run > Run Configurations..._ launch configuration of closed projects are filtered out, but not yet in the so-called _Launch Bar_. Please report it as an enhancement to Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hand, @howlger! And your comment also pull me to dig into the toolbar setting... great forum having people like you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @howlger I have found more insights on the toolbar settings of Eclipse.

In general, Eclipse default toolbar lineup are overdone for beginners like me. It should be more concise and turn-up only needed thus more intuitive.

The "Launch Bar" makes it explicit and standing out. But those build/debug functions/buttons are already in basic toolbar set, thus would be redundant or even misleading if people click on the drop-down menu of "Launch configuration", which is also not clean & clear in principal.

For that reason, the Launch Bar could be disable (for beginners):

```
Preference=>Launching=>Launch bar | right panel=> uncheck 
  Enable the Launch Bar
```

The red-squared button of terminate could be useful while debugging and re-build, because the previous malfunctioning RUN & program could still resident in task manager thus prevent further build and turn-up permission error, There helps this "Terminate" button instead of restart Eclipse. BUT as said, this button also in basic toolbar set. But it is often shadowed by the out-standing Launching Bar :-).

It is also possible to [fully customize the toolbar](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-43f.htm) (and lock it):

```
Windows=>Perspective=>Customize Perceptive
```

Then choose the tool bar items to display.
For the issue of multiple historical "launching configurations", I will report to Eclipse.